# Data sets for evaluating text retrieval quality

Tags: dataset, text-mining, similarity, information-retrieval

I'm searching for data sets for evaluating text retrieval quality.

TF-IDF is a popular similarity measure, but is it the best choice? And which *variant* is the best choice? [Lucenes Scoring](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) for example uses IDF^2, and IDF defined as 1+log(numdocs/(docFreq+1)). TF in lucene is defined as sqrt(frequency)...

Many more variants exist, including [Okapi BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25), which is used by the [Xapian search engine](http://xapian.org/docs/bm25.html)...

I'd like to study the different variants, and I'm looking for **evaluation data sets**. Thanks!

Comment: This is off topic in this Stack Exchange. Your post belongs in: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is seeking a data set, and I believe that is more specifically on-topic at opendata.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

TF IDF will give you the degree of measure of how relevant a document is to your query. owever, to evaluate your IR system you need to use metrics such as - Precision, Recall and F score.

Precision: Out of all the documents that your system retrieves, which ones are relevant? This measures how much noise there is in the output of your IR system.

Recall: Out of all the documents that are relevant, which ones did your system retrieve? This measures how much coverage does your IR system have?

It is possible to get 100% recall all the time by basically retrieving ALL documents from a collection for any query. However, the precision in this case will be very low.

It is possible to get a very high precision by hand modeling an IR system ti produce very accurate results. However, it would produce a very bad recall as there will not be coverage over all the documents.

So we need to measure F score- which is the harmonic mean between Precision and Recall
Check out [Chapter 8 of the Stanford IR book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/08eval.pdf).

If you are looking for datasets only here are a few that are relevant:

- http://zitnik.si/mediawiki/index.php?title=Datasets
- http://www.daviddlewis.com/resources/testcollections/
- http://boston.lti.cs.cmu.edu/callan/Data/